# Not able to open ChromeDriver in foreground in Ubuntu linux

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running the Selenium test script in Ubuntu and trying to open the Chrome-driver, but it always runs in background process. Is there any special permission that we have to configure?
[image: ubuntu screenshot]

Comment: What are you trying to validate bringing _ChromeDriver_ process in the foreground?

Comment: I am running Selenium web-driver test script so I need to test the UI if the test is going fine or not

Comment: So its firing all well, but why do you want the process in the foreground?